# RefreshToken undefined after successful Authentication ServiceStack

Tags: typescript, servicestack

- ServiceStack Version 5.0
- ServiceStack Typescript Client Version 0.0.40

The following code calls my Auth microservice and successfully authenticates a user and returned there bearer token:

```
var request = new Authenticate();
request.provider = "credentials";
request.userName = userName;
request.password = password;
request.useTokenCookie = true;

this.client.post(request)
.then(res => {
    if (res.bearerToken != null) {
    console.log('auth success', res);
    console.log('auth refresh token', res.refreshToken);
    resolve(true);
    }
    resolve(false);
}, msg => {
    console.log('log in failed');
    reject(msg);
})
```

The problem is there is no refresh token return from my Auth microservice:

[image]

My configuration for my Auth Microservice:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new JwtAuthProvider
        {
            HashAlgorithm = AuthSettings.HashAlgorithm,
            RequireSecureConnection = requireSecureConnection,
            AuthKeyBase64 = AuthSettings.JwtAuthKeyBase64,
            ExpireTokensIn        = TimeSpan.FromHours(_configuration["AuthSettings:ExpireTokensIn"].ToDouble()),
            ExpireRefreshTokensIn = TimeSpan.FromHours(_configuration["AuthSettings:ExpireRefreshTokensIn"].ToDouble()),
            CreatePayloadFilter = (payload,session) => {
                    payload["zipCode"] = ((CustomUserSession)session).ZipCode;
            },
            PopulateSessionFilter = AuthSettings.PopulateSessionFilterImplementation
        },
        new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider((ITsoContext)_serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITsoContext))) //HTML Form post of User/Pass
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're overriding `CredentialsAuthProvider` with a Custom AuthProvider make sure you're also [setting Authentication was performed](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/a5bc5f5a96fb990b69dcad9dd5e95e688477fd94/src/ServiceStack/Auth/CredentialsAuthProvider.cs#L236) with:

```
authService.Request.Items[Keywords.DidAuthenticate] = true;
```

Support for JWT RefreshTokens also [requires a registered AuthRepository](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#requires-user-auth-repository).

If you're using a Custom AuthProvider without an `IAuthRepository` I've just added support for implementing `IUserSessionSource` as an alternative source to populating Sessions in new JWT Tokens, which you can utilize by registering it in your IOC or having your Custom AuthProvider implement:

```
public interface IUserSessionSource
{
    IAuthSession GetUserSession(string userAuthId);
}
```

The implementation should only return a populated `IAuthSession` if they're allowed to sign-in, i.e. if their account is suspended it should throw an Exception like:

```
throw HttpError.Forbidden("User is suspended");
```

Support for `IUserSessionSource` is available from ServiceStack v5 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget). Please [review v5 changes](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/myget-pre-release-packages-upgraded-to-v5/4749/1) before upgrading.

Comment: thanks @mythz, I set that Request property to true in my OnAuthenticated override but still no RefreshToken

Comment: do I need persistence for RefreshTokens? I am not currently storing anything in any database, I have a legacy database that I am working with

Comment: @BrianOgden That's the issue then, it [requires an AuthRepository](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#requires-user-auth-repository) which is what it uses to populate tokens without re-authenticating.

Comment: If I would like a token that does not expire for a long period of time, then my only option with my current implementation, is to just increase the expiration time of my bearer token, sound correct?

Comment: @BrianOgden Yeah, if you’re not using an AuthRepository

Comment: do you have any documentation or examples of implementing the persistence for the RefreshTokens, I cannot have the a ServiceStack AuthRepository scaffolding all the auth persistence tables, I have legacy user credentials table

Comment: @BrianOgden RefreshTokens needs an IAuthRepository, there is no alternative.

Comment: Will IAuthRepository scaffold tables in the database for User, Session etc?

Comment: @BrianOgden Calling InitSchema will create the UserAuth/UserAuthDetails tables if they don’t exist, User Sessions are stored in the ICacheClient, not the AuthRepo.

Comment: Do I need to call InitSchema to setup my persistence correctly for to use RefreshCookies?

Comment: @BrianOgden It creates the tables to persist Users, not RefreshTokens, they aren’t persisted. The IAuthRepository is used to be able to populate fresh JWT Tokens without going through an AuthProvider. If you’re not persisting Users in an AuthRepo you won’t be able to use RefreshTokens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159512/discussion-between-brian-ogden-and-mythz).

Comment: @BrianOgden Please see my updated answer for new support for having your Custom AuthProvider implement `IUserSessionSource`. If you have issues with the new provider please submit a new question.