# Why do my ServiceStack APIs seem to use an in memory Bearertoken for refresh until it expires

Tags: servicestack

I have JWT Token based stateless Auth architecture.

My client includes a valid RefreshToken token in all HTTP Requests to my ServiceStack APIs. The RefreshToken has a 7 day expiration, something like:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(url);
client.refreshToken = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1RSIiwiYWxnIjoiSFMyNTYiLCJraWQiOiJNak0ifQ.eyJzdWIiOjQwMCwiaWF0IjoxNTE4NTY5NTIzLCJleHAiOjE1MTkxNzQzMjN9.SIyrFYj5BXolp-RhuhdTb2p1jRwzyj6rzr5QeHxvyyc"

var req = MyRequest();
client.get(request)
...
```

I noticed that, upon logout, logging out meaning I simply nulled out the RefreshToken in client storage, and then logging in as a different user I would sometimes get data response back from my APIs for the previous logged in user.

I debugged this by watching this method in my Auth API:

```
/// <summary>
/// ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47441598/how-to-correctly-implement-iusersessionsource-servicestack
/// </summary>
/// <param name="userAuthId"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public IAuthSession GetUserSession(string userAuthId)
{
    var claims = _tsoContext.GetClaims(Convert.ToInt32(userAuthId));
    var customUserSession = new CustomUserSession();

    HydrateCustomUserSession(claims.ToList(), customUserSession);

    return customUserSession;
}
```

The GetUserSession method gets called by other APIs so those APIs can get a fresh BearerToken based on the userAuthId in the RefreshToken.

I think it important to note [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47441598/how-to-correctly-implement-iusersessionsource-servicestack) where @mythz and ServiceStack team make a change so I can use stateless tokens with my own custom auth credentials and persistence.

I noticed that `GetUserSession` was only being called around every minute, by my APIsl toggling logouts between users. It also seemed that the Refresh token always had the right userAuthId but the BearToken was stale.

My BearerToken had `a one minute long expiration` on it. I changed the BearerToken to expire in 1 second:

```
 ExpireTokensIn = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
```

This fixed my issues, rapidly toggling login/logouts between two users.

My question is this though, the RefreshToken had a different userAuthId, then the BearerToken, seemingly stored in memory in my APIs. It seems ServiceStack would use this BearerToken with a minute expiration time, no matter the userAuthId mismatch between the RefreshToken and the BearerToken.

Comment: There are no persistence of JWT Bearer Tokens or Refresh Tokens, i.e. the Server has no reference to any previous JWT Tokens it's created previously beyond the life of the Request. RefreshTokens themselves is only used to fetch new JWT Bearer Tokens which is what encapsulates the Users Session that's sent with each request. If you're reusing the same client instance you also need to clear the `BearerToken`. If the issue still persists can you update your question with the Raw HTTP Request/Response Headers as that's the ultimate source which shows what's really happening.

Comment: @mythz thanks, you are correct, an in memory bearer token from the previous session was still being passed in Requests client side